# LISP : Counting Sub strings to check occurrences

Tags: lisp

```
(defun count-sub (str pat)
 (loop with z = 0 with s = 0 while s do
       (when (setf s (search pat str :start6 s))
         (incf z) (incf s (length pat)))
       finally (return z))))
```

Right so i have this code for counting sub strings but it will only take to sub string inputs at a time, how do i get it to take in more inputs ?

I.e. so the input would be like:

(count-sub "abcde" "a" "d" "e" "c")

instead of just:
(count-sub "abcd" "a")

Comment: Isn't `(count-sub "abcde" "a" "b")` equal to `(+ (count-sub "abcde" "a") (count-sub "abcde" "b"))` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would have it so that the unary function has a different name:

```
(defun count-sub-1 (str pat)
 (loop with z = 0 with s = 0 while s do
       (when (setf s (search pat str :start2 s)) ;; :start6 typo fixed
         (incf z) (incf s (length pat)))
       finally (return z))))
```

Then the N-ary API function is just a reduce job over this:

```
(defun count-sub (str &rest patterns)
  (reduce #'+ patterns :key (lambda (item) (count-sub-1 str item))))
```

Some tests:

```
(count-sub "aabc") -> 0
(count-sub "aabc" "a") -> 2
(count-sub "aabc" "a" "a") -> 4
(count-sub "aabc" "b") -> 1
(count-sub "aabc" "a" "b") -> 3
```

**You have a bug in your logic, however. If a pattern is the empty string, you get an infinite loop, because `(incf s (length pat))` doesn't change the value of `s`:**

```
(count-sub "abc" "") -> #<non-termination!>
```

A possible fix is:

```
(incf s (min (length pat) 1))
```

to always advance by at least one character, in the event of a zero length match. In this case, the empty string will match numerous times in the target string; if that is undesirable (you want an empty pattern to result in zero) then a check has to be put against that:

```
(if (plusp (length pat))
  (loop ...)
  0)
```

Then the `(min (length pat) 1)` compensation is unnecessary.